# How to convert a string to a date from dd mmm yyyy format in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

In SQL Server I have a query stripping a date from a string and need to convert to a real date format to join with another date.

string = '07 Nov 2014'

I've tried cast (string as date) but get 'Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.'

Comment: what version of sql server ?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql look there for `B. FORMAT with custom formatting strings`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the following using [`CONVERT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql):

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATE, string, 106)

-- example
SELECT CONVERT(DATE, '07 Nov 2014', 106) -- 2014-11-07
```

You can find a list with all date and time styles (3rd parameter - `106`) on the [microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql#date-and-time-styles). You can also find a [working demo on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1e1f4fbf1/18168/0).

Answer (score -1):

you can convert like this,

```
select convert(date,'27 NOV 2001 00:00:00',104) as [MM/dd/YYYY]
```